# could not initialize opengles emulation use '-gpu off' to disable it

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-virtual-device

I am getting an error with my Xamarin portable application deployment/run in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Error message said that

> there were deployment errors, continue?
>   additional error message: could not initialize opengles emulation use '-gpu off' to disable it

I find various solution regarding this problem but most of these are based on android studio and rest of solution (VS) doesn't worked for me.

**My system information:** 
Windows 10, Intel Core Duo e8400 32 bit processor.

Isn't my system  good enough for Xamarin application or there are any solution on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same configuration with you (this processor is 64 bit BTW!). Did you find a solution to your problem? I yes, then can you post it as an answer here?

Comment: same issue, is this related to hardware virtualisation... or something specific with the GPU? I have updated the Video drivers to latest...